# Create a certain htmlstructure with the loop in wordpress for Parentpages/Childpages

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, fullpage.js

Had no idea how to describe my problem, but hope it made any sense. Im trying to invoke fullpage.js (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/README.md)to a wordpress theme, and it works fairly good so far. The script uses divs for slides, and nested divs for horizontal slides inside a parent slide. Like this:

`<div class="section">
        <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div> 
        <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
        <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div> 
        <div class="slide"> Slide 4 </div> 
    </div>`

However, I'm using code from this place: http://www.themevan.com/build-an-one-page-portfolio-website-with-wordpress/?codekitCB=413560456.282228 To create anchor links for each page, and i run this loop to make a slide from every page made:

`<div id="pageSlide-<?php echo $post->post_name;?>" class="section" data-anchor="<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">`

This works great, but makes it hard to do horizontal slides. Is there anyway to create a loop that creates the needed htmlstructure for pages and child pages?

Comment: You should reduce your problem for people to understand what you want. You should forget about naming fullpage.js. Just get centered on creating the needed HTML structure by using PHP.